# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, android-layout

`RecyclerView`と`CardView`を使ってリストを作ったいるのですが､`Adapter`内の`onCreateViewHolder`でアイテム用の`CardView`をinflateするときに以下のエラーが出てしまいます｡

```html
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
```

`LayoutInflater`が取得出来ていないかと考えたのですが､取得出来ていましたし､アイテムに入れるべきデータもしっかりと取得出来ていました｡ 
`Adapter`は以下のようになっていて､Activityの内部クラスとして定義されています｡

```html
private class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ViewHolder>{

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private List<Video> mVideoInfo;
        private Context mContext;
        private int mResourceId;

        public SearchAdapter(Context context, int resourceId){
            super();
            mContext=context;
            mResourceId=resourceId;
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mVideoInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
            View v = mInflater.inflate(mResourceId, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount(){
            return (null != mVideoInfo ? mVideoInfo.size() : 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
            Video item = mVideoInfo.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(item.title);
            holder.duration.setText(item.duration);
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(item.thumbnails.medium.url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.thumbnail_background_480)
                    .transform(new ViewUtils.YouTubeThumbnailEditor())
                    .into(holder.thumbnail);
        }


        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener{
            TextView title;
            ImageView thumbnail;
            TextView companyAndGoods;
            TextView duration;
            ImageView optionButton;
            RelativeLayout item;

            public ViewHolder(View v){
                super(v);
                title = findById(v, R.id.title);
                thumbnail = findById(v, R.id.thumbnail);
                companyAndGoods = findById(v, R.id.company_and_goods);
                duration = findById(v, R.id.duration);
                optionButton = findById(v, R.id.option_button);
                item = findById(v, R.id.item);
                optionButton.setTag(OPTION + mVideoInfo.get(getAdapterPosition()).id);
                optionButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                item.setTag(VIDEO+mVideoInfo.get(getAdapterPosition()).id);
                item.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tag = (String)v.getTag();
                if(tag.substring(0, VIDEO.length()).equals(VIDEO)){
                    moveToVideoActivity(tag.substring(VIDEO.length()));
                }else if(tag.substring(0, OPTION.length()).equals(OPTION)){
                    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(SearchActivity.this, v);
                    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.video_option_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
                    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
                    popupMenu.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                //TODO : お気に入り処理
                return false;
            }
        }
        public void addAll(List<Video> object) {
            mVideoInfo.addAll(object);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }
```

次の`onCreate()`の箇所で`RecyclerView`を初期化しています｡

```html
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mAdapter = new SearchAdapter(this, R.layout.search_item);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

また`RecyclerView`とアイテム用の`CardView`は以下のようになっています｡

**RecyvlerView**

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@color/background"/>
```

**CardView**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="?attr/cardCornerRadius"
    android:clickable="true">

    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:mrl_rippleColor="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="480px"
                android:layout_height="270px"
                android:contentDescription="@string/sample_image"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/option_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
                android:contentDescription="@string/sample_image"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/option_button"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/option_button"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/duration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/company_and_goods"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/duration"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/duration"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

何度もデバッグしてみたのですが､原因となる箇所を特定できませんでした｡ なにかこのエラーを回避する方法がありましたら教えていただけるとありがたいです｡  よろしくおねがいします｡

Comment: `MaterialRippleLayout`というサードパーティライブラリを使っているようですが、これをちゃんとプロジェクトに入ってありますか？

Comment: 入っているはずです。dependenciesですが。他の箇所でも使われていますが正常に動作しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これを

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ・・・省略
    app:cardCornerRadius="?attr/cardCornerRadius"
    ・・・省略
```

こうすればいいと思います。

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ・・・省略
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp" <!-- もしくはこの行を削除 -->
    ・・・省略
```

Comment: ありがとうございます｡ 解決しました｡  でもなんでですか? 他のところでは前者でうごいているのですが｡｡｡